# Avoiding warning from GLib with GLib.source_remove()

Tags: python, glib

When I need a part of my program that has GLib timeout functions set with

```
self.timeout_id = GLib.timeout_add_seconds(refresh, self._check_price)
```

I use

```
def stop(self):
    if self.timeout_id:
        GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
```

to make sure this `timeout_id` still exists before attempting to remove it.

Yet I still get these pesky error messages from time to time:

> Warning: Source ID 443 was not found when attempting to remove it
>   GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)

how do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is obviously getting removed via some other control path than `stop()`. The only candidate I can think of here (from the code you’ve provided) is the `self._check_price` method. If you’re returning `False`/`GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE` from that, you should also unset `self.timeout_id`:

```
def _check_price(self):
    …
    self.timeout_id = 0
    return GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE
```

Comment: aha. So I was hoping it would be automatically unset if the source was removed. Not so then! I'll test a little more and accept if it works. Many thanks!

Comment: How could it be automatically unset? You haven’t passed a pointer `&self.timeout_id` to GLib anywhere.

Comment: Seems logical in hindsight but I lack the knowledge and find the documentation for GLib and GTK somewhat difficult to understand. This works fine, thank you :)

Comment: If there are specific bits of documentation which you find confusing or lacking, please file a bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib), but note that we can only really improve the docs if given specific examples of where they’re lacking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use this :

```py
def stop(self):
    if self.timeout_id:
        GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
        self.timeout_id = None
```

Then the warning message disappears :

*Warning: Source ID 350 was not found when attempting to remove it*